# Windows Terminal - Launch powershell with different profile

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, windows-terminal

How can I configure windows terminal to launch Powershell with a separate profile other than my standard `$Profile`?

---

This would be helpful to have import modules like `posh-git` and `psreadline` only in the Powershell instance that I launch from `wt.exe` rather than from `pwsh.exe`

Comment: Do you already have Powershell setup to run profiles other than the profiles files that are default in `$Profile`? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can source a custom Powershell (`.ps1`) profile file as you invoke `pwsh.exe` or `powershell.exe` from `wt.exe`. For example a `posh-git` profile in Windows Terminal settings.json Would look something like this:

```
{
    "guid": "{01463d52-dda9-4109-b03f-c55899b52df2}",
    "name": "Powershell - Posh Git",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -noprofile -noexit -command \"invoke-expression '. ''C:/PsProfilePoshGit.ps1''' \"",
    "icon": "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}.png",
    "hidden": false
},
```

You can generate a unique guid for each new profile you add by running the command `[guid]::NewGuid()` in Powershell.

Finally your dedicated Powershell profile file: `C:/PsProfilePoshGit.ps1` would look something like this (at a minimum):

```bsh
Import-Module posh-git
function global:prompt
{
    Write-Host -Object "Posh-Git" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta
 
    return "> "
}
```

Comment: in the newer WT.exe settings gui I put this under `command line`: ```%ProgramFiles%\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -noexit -noprofile -f %USERPROFILE%\GIT_profile.ps1```